# DocumentDB show all documents of specific entity type

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a generic `IDocumentDbRepository` repository for providing basic CRUD operations with DocumentDB and specific repositories for additional operations with specific entities, which inherits or implements this interface and class.

```
    public interface IDocumentDbRepository<T> where T : class
{
    //IEnumerable<T> GetItems();
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync();
    Task<T> GetItemAsync(T id);
    Task<T> AddDocumentAsync(T item);
    Task<T> UpdateDocumentAsync(T id, T item);
    Task DeletedocumentAsync(T id);
}

public class DocumentDbRepository<T> : IDocumentDbRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly string AuthKey;
    private readonly string EndpointUri;
    private readonly string DatabaseId;
    private readonly string CollectionId;
    private static DocumentClient client;


    public DocumentDbRepository(IOptions<DocumentDbSettings> DocumentDbConfig)
    {
        this.DatabaseId = DocumentDbConfig.Value.DatabaseName;
        this.CollectionId = DocumentDbConfig.Value.CollectionName;
        this.AuthKey = DocumentDbConfig.Value.AuthKey;
        this.EndpointUri = DocumentDbConfig.Value.EndpointUri;
        client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndpointUri), AuthKey);
    }

public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync()
{
     IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
     UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId))
     .AsDocumentQuery();

    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
    }
    return results;
}

   // public IEnumerable<T> GetItems()
   // {
   //     var results = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>//(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId)).ToList();
   //   return results;
   // }
//methods
```

In my specific `Employee` repository I aim to return only documents of type `Employee`

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository : IDocumentDbRepository<Employee>
{
    List<Employee> GetAllEmployees();
}

public class EmployeeRepository : DocumentDbRepository<Employee>, IEmployeeRepository
{
    public EmployeeRepository(IOptions<DocumentDbSettings> DocumentDbConfig) : base(DocumentDbConfig)
    {

    }

    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return GetItems().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Employee)).ToList(); 
    }
}
```

I call `GetAllEmployees` method in my controller to only list Documents of Type `Employee`in my View, but it does not work and all documents with whatever entity type gets listed. What am I doing wrong ?

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_employeeRepository.GetAllEmployees());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, several things.

First you should never call `.ToList();` on `CreateDocumentQuery` like that. It will make multiple synchronous calls over the wire in order to return every single document in the database. This will cause insane RU/s and really bad performance.

Use `AsDocumentQuery` and call `ExecuteNextAsync` while `query.HasMoreResults`.

Second, by the time you call the `ToList()` method, everything is returned as an Employee because you queried for it that way. You basically said, "return me everything in this collection as an Employee and then from that return me the Employees". At this stage all of them are Employees.

What you really need is some sort of `type` property on your document which you can use to query for before you do the `ToList` call.

I would recommend you check how [collection sharing](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#collection-sharing) works in [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut). Sounds exactly like something you need.

[Here](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/blob/develop/Cosmonaut/Extensions/CosmosResultExtensions.cs#L137) is how you can asynchronously call the ToList method without blocking the thread.

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of Cosmonaut.*

Comment: Thank for answer, will make use of your tips. To that property type. You mean I should create something like `public bool isEmployee` property in my `Employee` model and in my `EmployeeRepository` I shall query to return only entities where `isEmployee==true` ?

Comment: Not quite. If it is a boolean then you are limited to two different types. Just create an interface with a single property named something like `EntityType` and make your Dtos implement it. Then you can do a `Where(x=>x.EntityType == nameof(Employee)).ToListAsync()` in order to query just what you need.

Comment: I edited my question and created `GetItemsAsync()` method based on your advice is that how it should be ? Also created interface which is now implemented by my `Employee` model and it has now `EntityType` property. I would like to return only Employee entities from `GetAllEmployees()` in my `EmployeeRepository` but despite your advices im kinda lost, could you please provide some code how to do that in there ? Sorry Im new to CosmosDB.

Comment: You have to change the `where T : class` to `where T : IYourInterface` and then you should be able to do something like this `IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId)).Where(x=>x.EntityType == nameof(T)).AsDocumentQuery();`

Comment: You mean change `where T : IYourInterface` in `DocumentDBRepository<T>` ? How it will help, is that even possible?. I would like to reuse that generic `GetItemsAsync()` method in my `EmployeeRepository` and there make query in some method based on items i already recieved by `GetItemsAsync()` method

Comment: It would because you would be able to use the interface property in the LINQ query. That way it will be serialized and the sql generated in the library will limit your results. The only thing you need to do is to have your T objects implement your interface in order to share this common property.

Comment: I got what you mean. It is working now thanks for help.