# How to get all items from a specific type in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following DocumentDBRepository

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace TenantManagementWebApi.DataAccess
{
    public static class DocumentDBRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private static readonly string DatabaseId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["database"];
        private static readonly string CollectionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["collection"];
        private static DocumentClient client;

        public static async Task<T> GetItemAsync(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                Document document = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id));
                return (T)(dynamic)document;
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
                new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
                .Where(predicate)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            }

            return results;
        }

        public static async Task<Document> CreateItemAsync(T item)
        {
            return await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId), item);
        }

        public static async Task<Document> UpdateItemAsync(string id, T item)
        {
            return await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id), item);
        }

        public static async Task DeleteItemAsync(string id)
        {
            await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id));
        }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]);
            CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
            CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync().Wait();
        }

        private static async Task CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId));
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    await client.CreateDatabaseAsync(new Database { Id = DatabaseId });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task CreateCollectionIfNotExistsAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await client.ReadDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId));
            }
            catch (DocumentClientException e)
            {
                if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
                        UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(DatabaseId),
                        new DocumentCollection { Id = CollectionId },
                        new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 1000 });
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to get all items from a specific type (eg Tenant)

```
  public class TenantController : ApiController
    {
        private static DocumentClient client;

        public TenantController()
        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["endpoint"]), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authKey"]);
        }

        public async Task<IQueryable<Tenant>> GetTenants()
        {
            return await  DocumentDBRepository<IQueryable<Tenant>>.GetItemsAsync());
        }
```

Error is obvious:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'predicate' of 'DocumentDBRepository<IQueryable<Tenant>>.GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<IQueryabl
```

BUt I need to send no predicate because I want to get all items from a specific type of object:

```
 public class Tenant
    {
        public string TenantId { get; set; }
        public string TenantUrl { get; set; }
        public string CertificatePath { get; set; }
        public string CertificatePassword { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51171569/documentdb-show-all-documents-of-specific-entity-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public async Task<List<Tenant>> GetTenants()
{
    return await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.GetItemsAsync().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Won't this just return everything in the collection but it will try to map them as Tenants? Also what you posted is not valid C#. The result needs to be wrapped in parenthesis `(await DocumentDBRepository<Tenant>.GetItemsAsync()).ToList();`

Comment: @NickChapsas
Of course this will return everything just like the OP wants. Usually you want a filtered / paged collection to return from your controller. Not everything in your resource. Which can be thousands of records.

Comment: I want all items in the DB of type Tenant. I know this is a small DB, it will never grow to more than 100 records.

Comment: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Cosmonaut 1.4.7'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not 
contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Your project targets .net4.6 which Cosmonaut 1.4.7 package does not support.
Refer the package support which framework versions are supported